# Extract items from array: between given values/conditions

Tags: python, indexing, numpy, slice

I have a number of timeseries data in arrays and wish to extract values between given dates in the simplest way possible avoiding loops.
Here's an example:

```
from numpy import *
from datetime import *

# datetime array
date_a=array([
datetime(2000,1,1),
datetime(2000,1,2),
datetime(2000,1,3),
datetime(2000,1,4),
datetime(2000,1,5),
])

# item array, indices corresponding to datetime array
item_a=array([1,2,3,4,5])

# extract items in a certain date range
# after a certain date, works fine
item_b=item_a[date_a >= (datetime(2000,1,3))] #Out: array([3, 4, 5])

# between dates ?
item_c=item_a[date_a >= (datetime(2000,1,3)) and date_a <= (datetime(2000,1,4))]
# returns: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Is there a one-line solution to this? I have looked at numpy `any()` and `all()`, and also `where()`, without being able to find a solution. I appreciate any help and point-in-direction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want one-liner, then you can use

```
item_c=item_a[(date_a >= (datetime(2000,1,3))) * (date_a <= (datetime(2000,1,4)))]
```

Comment: Brilliant, just what I was searching for! Thanks :)

Comment: Just FYI: `&` is much more readable than `*`, here, and it does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear to me why you are using the `item_a` variable. But to isolate the entries you want you can simply do:

```
>>> np.where(np.logical_and(date_a >= datetime(2000,1,3), date_a <= datetime(2000,1,4)))
(array([2, 3]),)
```

The resulting indexes are zero-based, so they correspond to the third and fourth element of your array.

**EDIT:** `np` is due to `import numpy as np`. Doing `from numpy import *` is in fact a very **bad idea**. You will overwrite built in functions such as `sum` and `abs` for example...

HTH!

Comment: thanks! coming from matlab there is still plenty learn about python behaviour :) this answer and the one from @Andrey Sobolev was exactly what I was looking for. item_a was just to get the values of the array, but indeed not needed as it is the indices I'm interested in

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should work for you using [List Comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```
[item_a[i] for i in xrange(0,len(date_a)) if date_a[i] >= (datetime(2000,1,3)) and date_a[i] <= (datetime(2000,1,4))]
```

Select all items in item_a  within `range 0 <= i < length of date_a where   datetime(2000,1,3) <=  date_a[i] <= datetime(2000,1,4)`

Comment: Works like a charm! I'm trying to avoid loops though due to very large datasets, but I will test this implementation as well.