# Most efficient way to extract parts of one array based on another

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a time series with about 150 million points. I need to zoom in on 3 million points. That is, **I need to extract the 100 time points surrounding each of those 3 million areas of interest in this 150 million point time series**.

**Attempt:**

```
 def get_waveforms(data,spiketimes,lookback=100,lookahead=100):
      answer = zeros((len(spiketimes),(lookback+lookahead)))
      duration = len(data)
      for i in xrange(len(spiketimes)):
          if(spiketimes[i] - lookback) > 0 and spiketimes[i] + lookahead) < duration:
               answer[i,:] = data[(spiketimes[i]-lookback):(spiketimes[i]+lookahead)]
      return answer
```

This eats up all available memory on my Mac. It explodes if I try to pass and array of where `len(array) > 100000`. Is there a more memory efficient or (hopefully) more elegant approach to pull out parts of one array based on another?

**Related**
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325089/extract-items-from-array-between-given-values-conditions?rq=1) answer is related. However, I'm not exactly sure how to apply it and avoid a loop. Would I, effectively, be indexing the time series vector over and over with the columns of a boolean matrix?

Comment: Do you need to get all of them at once?  What are you doing with each waveform afterwards?

Comment: I'm going to do PCA (well, SVD) on the waveform matrix. In between getting the waveforms and doing that, I can save the waveforms piecemeal to file (if I figure out how to do that). However, I will need to access all waveforms at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allocating an array of `200 * len(spiketimes)` floats, so for your 100,000 item `spiketimes` should only be about 160 MB, which doesn't seem like much. On the other hand, if you go to 1,000,000 `spiketimes`, a 1.6 GB single array may be a stretch for some systems. If you have the memory, you can vectorize the extraction with something like this:

```
def get_waveforms(data, spiketimes, lookback=100, lookahead=100) :
    offsets = np.arange(-lookback, lookahead)
    indices = spiketimes + offsets[:, None]
    ret = np.take(data, indices, mode='clip')
    ret[:, spiketimes < lookback] = 0
    ret[:, spiketimes + lookahead >= len(data)] = 0
    return ret
```

The handling of the `spiketimes` too close to the edges of `data` mimics that in your function with loops.

The wise thing to do when you have so much data is to take views into it. That is harder to vectorize (or at least I haven't figured how to), but since you aren't copying any of the data, the python loop will not be much slower:

```
def get_waveforms_views(data, spiketimes, lookback=100, lookahead=100) :
    ret = []
    for j in spiketimes :
        if j < lookback or j + lookahead >= len(data) :
            ret.append(None)
        else :
            ret.append(data[j - lookback:j + lookahead])
    return ret
```

With the following test data:

```
data_points, num_spikes = 1000000, 10000

data = np.random.rand(data_points)
spiketimes = np.random.randint(data_points, size=(num_spikes))
```

I get these timings:

```
In [2]: %timeit get_waveforms(data, spiketimes)
1 loops, best of 3: 320 ms per loop

In [3]: %timeit get_waveforms_views(data, spiketimes)
1 loops, best of 3: 313 ms per loop
```

Comment: I understand why this first function you wrote is better- I didn't know about the take function. Why is the second function faster or more memory efficient than mine? They look very similar.

Comment: @mac389 The first function is taking chunks of 200 items from your huge array, and copying those chunks to a new, even more ginormous array. Hence your memory problems. The second one is not doing any copying: each of the items appended to list do not own their data, they simply show a small window of your big array. This is much more memory efficient, and as shown above, it may perform comparably well despite the for loop. Of course, modifying an item in a view will mmodify the underlying array, and the value in overlapping views, so you need to be aware of what you are doing.